# how to display elements of a character vector one by one

Tags: r, shiny

I have a character vector `corpus`. I am trying to display each member of the vector one by one as I click the `Next` button. **How can I increment the `current` variable using `Next` button?**
So far I have the following code:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Display character vector one by one"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(actionButton("Next", "Next Sentence")),
  mainPanel( htmlOutput("content"))
)))

#server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  corpus <- c("Sample sentence one", "Second sentence", "Third sentence")
  current <- 1 
  observeEvent(input$Next,{
    if(current <= length(corpus))
    output$content <- renderText(corpus[current])
  })
})
```

**Please also suggest if there are better ways to achieve this functionality**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### The problem is:

In your `server.R`, you make the variable `current` local, so every time you click the button <kbd>**Next Sentence**</kbd>, it remains constantly `1`, as a result, it will always render the first element in your list, which is `Sample sentence one`.

#### Solution:

Make a **global** variable, increase by `1` after every time you click the button. In **RShiny**, use `<<-` to modify global variable instead of `<-`. Also check [Scoping rules for Shiny apps](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scoping.html).

#### So check:

```
current <- 0

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  corpus <- c("Sample sentence one", "Second sentence", "Third sentence")
  observeEvent(input$Next,{
    if(current <= length(corpus))
      output$content <- renderText(corpus[current])
    
    current <<- current %% length(corpus) + 1
  })
})
```

Comment: got what i wanted after two minor changes; `<=` in  if statement to `<` and `current <<- current + 1`

Comment: I'm glad you got what you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too, store the current index as reactive value and show the sentences circularly, with modulo arithmetic:

```
#ui.R
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Display character vector one by one"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(actionButton("Next", "Next Sentence")),
                mainPanel( htmlOutput("content"))
  )))

#server.R
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$current <- 0
  corpus <- c("Sample sentence one", "Second sentence", "Third sentence")
  observeEvent(input$Next,{
    output$content <- renderText(corpus[values$current])
    values$current <- values$current %% length(corpus) + 1
  })
})
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```